# Sniffing https/http traffic from entire OS with mitmproxy

Tags: debian, proxy, https, http-proxy

I'm using debian 8, and i want to capture all the traffic from it. So i installed mitmproxy on the same os on which i want to capture https, and i set up in the 'network->wifi->http proxy and https proxy'. But in doesnt work, i don't see any packets going trough 127.0.0.1:8080, but if i manually put a proxy in firefox for example it does work. Can someone help with this, maybe i need to redirect 443 / 80 ports to localhost:8080 with iptables or something like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [mitmproxy docs](https://mitmproxy.org/doc/transparent/linux.html) explain how to use `iptables` to redirect ports 80 and 443.

If you want to run mitmproxy it on the same machine, nearly all other methods require to configure the application you want to capture to use a proxy. I'm not sure what *network->wifi->http proxy and https proxy* does, because I don't have that on my Debian system, but many applications
understand a `http_proxy` environment variable, which you can set in your `~/.profile` or explicitely:

```
export http_proxy=http://localhost:8080/
```